# How can I determine the method used to launch my python script in Windows?

Tags: python

Is there a way to differentiate between a .py file launched by double-clicking its icon in Windows versus typing myscript.py in an existing command prompt window? My code ends with `os.system("pause")` so that I can see the results when double-clicking to launch, but that line should be ignored when running it in a persistent window.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can have your code running with `Pythonw.exe` which hides the terminal window and it can typically be done so if you use the `.pyw` extension.

Comment: It should be the responsibility of the user to configure their system to *not* automatically close the command window when the Python script exists.

Comment: @norok2 I want the opposite of that. I want the window to always be visible and always stay open to display the results of the script.

Comment: @chepner Could you describe how to ensure the window does not automatically close? I could not find a fool-proof method.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend you to go to advanced settings of your Windows Explorer and activate the "show extensions" options if that can help.

For more information about your question, you can also check this link :

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixb/